# Retrieve user info from Firebase and display in app

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Profile Page where I am trying to create a function, retrieveUserData, that will retrieve values from firebase, assign them to variables which I can then use to display in the html file.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage from '../../../pages/home/home';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Profile } from '../../../models/profile';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {

  name: string = "";
  hometown: string = "";

  constructor(private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){

  }

  onGoToHome(){
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage)
  }

  retrieveUserData(){
    var userId = this.afAuth.app.auth().currentUser.uid;


  }

}
```

I am trying to pull certain info from the firebase database to assign values to name and hometown and then use them in the html file. I have tried using the following examples from [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) doc, but the syntax is not working for me.. None of the syntax is being recognized. I know this is super trivial. Can someone help me with a clear example of the proper way to grab this data and use it. The table in firebase is called "profile".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is originating from you referencing the Firebase docs - when you are using the Angularfire2 package... Check out the Angularfire2 [documentation here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2).

In the mean time, I'll provide an example from one of my projects where I query the realtime database via Angularfire2 to help you along:

```
  this.afDatabase.database.ref(`profile/${userId }`).once('value').then( userDetailsAsObject => {

    let userDetails = userDetailsAsObject.val() ? userDetailsAsObject.val() : {};
    console.log(userDetails);

  }).catch( err => { 
    console.log('Error pulling /profile table inside functionName() inside componentName.component.ts'); 
    console.log(err); 
  });
```

---

EDIT per additional question in comments:
Assuming you have this kind of database structure...

```
profile
   |
   |--12bd02nasBD0Bd93nbD    (userID)
          |
          |--name:"John Smith"
          |
          |--hometown:"Paris, France"
```

Then the database query will return the `12bd02nasBD0Bd93nbD` node as one big object... so you would access properties of that object in the same manner as any other JavaScript object (*i.e. [dot notation or bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)*)

```
this.name = userDetails['name'];
this.hometown = userDetails['hometown'];
```

Then just reference the `name` and `hometown` variables in your HTML.

Comment: Thank you! I see the data showing up in the console. Do you know how I can target a particular piece of data? So in this I get the values for name and hometown, but how can I assign them to the variables I declared so I can use them in the HTML? Or is this better to do in the html itself.

Comment: I updated my answer to better explain that. It's personal preference whether to declare separate `name` and `hometown` variables... or instead you could create one `userDetails` variable and then just reference `userDetails.name` and `userDetails.hometown` in the HTML... your preference.